# 2 answers -- different reactions.

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, specific-answer

The following question:

[Regional Mathematics Olympiad 2018 Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3375898)

has received two answers. One, by @HagenvonEitzen, got 4 upvotes (I have upvoted it myself) and 1 downvote; and the other one (by me) got 1 upvote and 3 downvotes.

- Why downvotes?
- Why such a drastic voting difference?

I am just curious. But there is more to this than simple curiosity.

***P.S.***   The OP Question was a nice Olympic problem.

Comment: May be their answer is wrong? I did not read carefully, but it seems that the answer discuss rectangles while the question asks about squares.

Comment: @ArcticChar, you're right. Thank you. I have deleted my answer (a pity, it was a nice solution :) ).

Comment: It is not uncommon for answers to poor questions (in this case, no context, no interaction) to be downvoted, regardless of the quality of the answer. I suggest this explains some of the downvotes (both gained an extra downvote since you posted this question).

Comment: My question above was a gentle introduction to a much more basic issue about MATHEMATICS. The Olympic question mensioned above got removed, and this was wrong. Even more importantly, the whole attitude of several participants here is simply awful. This attitude is the same as by the worst teachers of mathematics. (I am not sure if there is any willingness around here to rectify this fundamental problem of teaching. It's ironic that such a false attitude is all too common here).

Comment: (PS. @ArcticChar, after my earlier miss, now I do have a decent, reasonably nice solution of that Olympic problem -- it was fun).

Comment: @WlodAA What attitude, precisely, are you referring to when you say "This attitude is the same as by the worst teachers of mathematics"? (I believe that the best teachers encourage students to interact with the subject, as mathematics is not passive. If a students walked into my office and asked me this problem I would reply with "where are you stuck?", and we would have a conversation. I would *not* regurgitate the answer, as that isn't teaching.)